# Charts losing named ranges, replaced with _{r1}, _{r9}, etc. Am I doing it wrong?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, crash, charts

I am using named ranges in a chart within which are OFFSET and INDEX/MATCH functions in order to drive dynamic chart behaviour based on changing the month in a cell.

A couple of times today as I have been building it, excel has crashed and the chart has lost the reference to the named ranges in the chart even though the file has been saved. The named ranges have instead been replaced with things like _{r1}, _{r2}, _{r9}, etc.

I believe the crashes have occurred when I have used CTRL-Z more than once consecutively.  For additional context, the file is a shared file on the network that multiple users can concurrently edit, although nobody else has been in the file while I have been making changes.

So, the named range formula will look something like the following, with the source cell for the lookup being the start date of a given month:-

```
=OFFSET(INDEX(Table1[Total Cumul. Mfd],MATCH('Daily Visual'!$C$1,Table1[Date],0)),0,0,DAY(EOMONTH('Daily Visual'!$C$1,0)),1)
```

And the reference within the chart when it is working looks like this:-

```
='DMS - Tier 3.xlsm'!Form.Cumul.Mfd
```

But when things go wrong, whilst the named range formula remains ok, the reference within the chart will be replaced with something like the following:-

```
=_{r9}
```

I've searched around but the _{r1} or _{r9} or whatever don't seem to generate many results, and although I can find one or 2 hits on google, I can't see that they have had answers.

Does anybody know if I am doing something incorrectly, or is this a known problem of some kind?  Is there a way to avoid it, besides my anecdotal assumption that it has something to do with multiple CTRL-Z iterations in succession?

**EDIT:-** Has happened again although not as a result of CTRL-Z activity.  Interestingly it has only affected the one same chart, and not the ones subsequently created using other named ranges on the same tab.  Additional context, this is a .xlsm sheet which had a macro on another tab.  I have removed this now to see if it was creating a problem.